# SciFi Book about living in a privileged tower

Tags: story-identification

I read the book probably in the 2000s, but it could have been published much earlier.

The basic premise is there is a building/tower to which people aspire to live. Why the surrounding areas are desolate/poor I do not recall. The protagonist gained entry (invited, I believe). The protagonist is on a high-speed walkway and is scared when it looked like a barrier is suddenly in front of them. It was just toilet paper, as the perpetrators of the hoax noted that the tower would not allow anything bad to happen (plus I think people could be evicted for bad behavior).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Oath of Fealty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Fealty_(novel)) by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle. The building is an arcology called *Todos Santos* constructed in a future dystopic Los Angeles.

The scene you remember is:

> There were boys on the walks. One slipped a coil of rope off his shoulder. Lunan watched in horror as he flung it high in the air. It floated down, unrolling, across the fast pedway ahead of Lunan. Boys on the other side caught it. They pulled it taut, leaning back with the effort.
>
> "Duck!" Lunan roared. He dropped to the belt and tried to sweep Cheryl's legs from under her. She danced back, laughing, fending him off. The rope caught her across the chest, and disintegrated. It was toilet paper.
>
> Lunan got up. "Swell. What if it was a real rope?"
>
> Cheryl was still laughing. "It can't be. The guards would stop them. Did you see anyone else duck?"

The novel is fairly standard Niven/Pournelle fare - not terrible but not amazing either - but for some reason that scene of throwing the toilet roll across the walkway has stayed in my memory for forty years. I recognised it instantly from your description.

Comment: "Think of it as evolution in action."

Comment: @Shawn Yes! :-)